# Adding a delay to packet processing (omnet++)

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++, inet

How do you add a delay in omnet++?

In a case where a packet needs to be processed by a node, and forwarded at a later time (if, for example was not intended for that node (I need to process these packets at the application layer)).

Does processing a packet take "0" simulation time? Or do packets have to be buffered and sent out at a later time (scheduled into the future)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a self-message to modelling a delay of processing.
It is described in [3.6 Modeling processing delay](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part3/#36-modeling-processing-delay) as well as [txc6.cc](https://docs.omnetpp.org/showfile/?url=tutorials/tictoc/code/txc6.cc) contains an example of adding 1 second delay.
By default processing a message takes 0 simulation seconds.

Comment: Hasn't `sendDelayed` the same effect? (and with a reduced maintainability cost than self-messages)

Comment: Indeed, you can use `sendDelayed()` to model delay during sending a packet.